# Removing VSCode Java added annotations

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, apache-beam, vscode-extensions, checker-framework

I'm using VSCode with a Java project and whenever I use it to generate code (i.e. implement unimplemented methods, extract variable etc.) it will add the following annotations (sometimes other):

- UnknownKeyFor
- NonNull
- Initialized

I would like to disable those but I can't find which extension does that nor can I find where that happens in the codebase.
Does anyone know where these are added in the codebase or where can this behavior be disabled?

[image]

**ADDED:**
As per comments it appears the issue is related to using Apache Beam (Versions 2.28.0 and higher) - it emits annotations by `checkerframework` that are picked up by the `vscode` code generator.
This means to reproduce any code that uses Apache Beam would suffice. E.g. https://github.com/srfrnk/demo/tree/main/beam-kafka2file

Comment: It looks like there is no such configuration yet. I reported it on [GitHub](https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-java/issues/3036) hoping for a response.

Comment: Please provide a sample code that can be used to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @ShengChen - added in the end of the description.

Comment: @srfrnk It's 404

Comment: Sorry it was private - try now @ShengChen

Comment: Could you provide some more detailed steps? The gif is no clear I can hardly see anything.

Comment: Try anything that would generate code... like "Implement unimplemented methods", "Extract local variable" etc...